# How to implement some sort of "nullable" types in Standard ML?

Tags: sml, smlnj

Say a define several datatypes in Standard ML:

```
datatype color = orange | navy | teal | silver | hsl of real * real * real;

datatype direction = east | north | west | south;
```

I then define a value that uses the above datatypes:

```
type Cursor = int * int * color * direction;

val cursor : Cursor = (0, 0, orange, east);
```

It's a "cursor" that has a position, drawing color, and a direction. **What I would like to is have its properties be initially undefined**. I could add a constructor to each `color` and `direction` datatypes (how would I do that with `int` position values?), like the following:

```
datatype color = orange | teal | silver | hsl of real * real * real | undefined;

datatype direction = east | north | west | south | undefined;

val cursor : Cursor = (0, 0, undefined, undefined);
```

I want to do this **without** having to explicitly define an additional `undefined` constructor for each datatype. Can you think of a good, clean solution? Some form of generics where I can simply use a form of an "undefined value", regardless of type. An analog to Javas `Nullable`, to put it coarsely.

My motivation is the properties of my cursor are initially undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this purpose, people usually use an [`option`](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/option.html) type.

Your resulting robot type would be:

```
type Robot = (int * int * color * direction) option;
```

or component wise.  This is also the same as simply making a data type with two constructors by yourself (one representing an undefined value, and one representing initialized values), but `option` is a standard way to do this that also encourages a monadic programming style.

This gets you type safety because you are required to match both constructors whenever you destruct values of the type.

Comment: Of course, how could I have missed this (have been reading on `option` already)! Thanks, I will try to incorporate this and get back and flag your answer as the correct one :-)

Answer (score 3):

There is no syntactic sugar for being able to refer to different constructors with the same name. (In other words: Standard ML does not allow custom overloading.) Instead, the constructor that is first declared is overwritten by a similarly spelled constructor of another type.

Haskell has a value called `undefined` that, when evaluated, throws an exception. The type of this value is therefore not constrained to any specific type and is polymorphic, which means that undefined can be used anywhere.

Standard ML cannot have this value defined as an alias to throwing an exception because it is strictly evaluated. This means that the moment `val undefined = raise Undefined` is declared, the exception is thrown. But it is possible to use `raise Undefined` in parts of a program that has not yet been written, so long as it is not evaluated straight away.

A very important strength of algebraic types is that you cannot accidentally have null-like values unless you explicitly form the types to support it (e.g. using `'a option`).

Comment: +1 for the comparison to `undefined` and noting that the reduction order in Haskell (vs. strict in ML) leads to a difference.